# tkinter некорректно работает и не отображает текст

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, macos

Пользуюсь MacBook m1pro c macOS Ventura 13.2.1.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x200")

label = ttk.Label(text="Hello", font=("Arial", 14), foreground="red")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

После запуска данного кода в PyCharm, в открывшемся окне не отображается текст.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, обратите внимание что имя и размер шрифта идут в общих кавычках:

```
label = ttk.Label(text="Hello", font="Arial 14", foreground="red")
```

Если этот код не заработает возможно стоит проверить на других шрифтах или шрифтах самого `tkinter`, таких как `TkDefaultFont` и т.п.

Так же можно посмотреть доступные семейства шрифтов:

```
from tkinter import font

for family in font.families():
    print(family)
```

А еще убедитесь что его версия не ниже `8.4`  для этого из консоли запустите:

```
python -m tkinter
```

должно всплыть окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у Вас проблемы с окружением. На моей системе (Fedora 37) всё работает нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, всем кто попытался мне помочь. По итогу у меня была проблема с tkinter, я переустановил его и у меня начло выводиться окно, как y Daniil Loban.

```
brew install tkinter

python -m tkinter
```

После я настроил интерпретатор в PyCharm.
И все заработало.